# MySQL memory usage for large database

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning, myisam

We have a MySQL DB (OLD_DATA) where many partitioned table size has gone over 100GB. To improve server performance we thought of creating a parallel DB (NEW_DATA) and start collecting new data in NEW_DATA.

The DBs are MyISAM and the server has 96GB RAM.

After this the OLD_DATA will not be accessed.

Will this approach help in improving server performance in terms of RAM and CPU usage?
Will the data from OLD_DATA be loaded in memory?

Comment: Databases generally don't load the entire database into memory at once.. the use of indices (and other clustering techniques) allows good algorithm selection and data access: i.e. only read what is need, when it is needed.

Comment: Depening on how you query new data and what for index setup you have. Just moving it to a new table wont guarantee any better performance. You have alot of memory so you should be able to build good indexes for fast queries

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree that indexing and optimal querying is essential. But I was looking to move to a new DB and in a way isolate the old DB, so that old DB does not hog memory.

Comment: @user1434805 Why *would* it "hog" main memory? The database will only load/cache disk pages when it deems such would be fitting. This should generally be far less than the size of the data on media.

Comment: @user1434805 Anyway, creating a new database won't intrinsically make the data access faster. But if "[OLD_DATA] will not be accessed" then it sounds like the "OLD_DATA" is to be turned into a historical archive - in which case establishing an archival system/process may be beneficial to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If it is, as you hinted, PARTITIONed, then we need to factor that into the analysis.

Generally if "old" rows are no longer accessed in any way, they do not hurt, and there would be no need to do what you did.  Please elaborate on the queries that you feel are "slow", preferably by providing `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

MyISAM caches index blocks in the "key_buffer"; how big are the indexes?  What is `key_buffer_size` set to?  Data blocks are cached by the OS.

It is quite 'normal' for a system to have a dataset that are many times as big as RAM.  Performance depends on the 'working set' of the dataset and on how actively you are querying the data.  You have implied that "old" rows are not used, hence not part of the 'working set'.

On the other hand, if you have "table scans", the entire table is part of the working set.  It is quite possible that we can advise on how to change those queries to be nicer.